# Unicode converting problems C++

Tags: unicode, locale

I'm encountering bizarre unicode related problems that I can't figure out.

Basically, I have a command line app that, when manually run from the command line, successfully calls mbtowcs() on a variety of inputs (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/mbstowcs/) manipulates the strings, and returns the proper output.

Whenever the app is run automatically via monit, this function isn't converting the correct number of bytes anymore, and the output is basically garbled and interspersed with the unicode error diamonds. I've tested this for the same inputs.

I suspect this is related to the locale or some setting on the machine (Ubuntu server 11.04). I am calling setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ""); successfully in my startup function.

Can anyone offer me advice on what system settings I should change to get my code to work properly?

Update: Looks like changing

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
```

to

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

May have solved the problem. Can anyone provide any information on why this is needed, or how I can change my system settings to avoid this?

Comment: Why do you call setlocale() in the first place? The UTF-8 is widely accepted as the default encoding of all strings on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the conversion from byte strings to `wchar_t` strings has to depend on locale. This is becayse the `mbstowcs` function needs to know the character encoding of input the byte string, and typically uses the locale to help it guess.

e.g. If your input bytes are:

```
C3 B6
```

Then if interpreted as UTF-8 its the string `ö` which is the `wchar_t` sequence of

```
00F6
```

But if interpreted as iso-8859-1 its the string `Ã¶` which is `wchar_t` sequence of

```
00C3 00B6
```

Now some byte sequences are not valid for certain encodings, which probable explains your unicode error diamonds. If you don't want to mess with the locale, you could look at using the `iconv` library instead. The `wchar_t` type usually corresponds to one of the UTF-32 encodings (LE or BE) but I'm not sure how portable that would be.

Comment: Useful if you are doing text/character analysis. e.g. detecting whitespace, letters, numbers etc.